# Creating Entity with MR_createEntity but managedObjectContext crashes on save

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

Basically i have a paginated request which gives me the data. I don't intend to save the data. But the Entity is passed to other viewController or other ViewController tried to write to persistance store it *crashes*.

**How can i use Entity without saving  Or if saving is the option how to do it?**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide crash report or the lines of code where it crashed?

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri : Edited question

Comment: While i was not saving the entity and going to another viewController

Comment: Creating entity with MR_Entity. How can i save it. If i have to?